# Implementing Cont Applicative instance

Tags: haskell, continuation-passing

I got the following error when implementing the Applicative instance for `Cont`.

> Couldn't match expected type ‘r’ with actual type ‘Cont r b’   ‘r’ is
>   a rigid type variable bound by ...

```
newtype Cont r a = Cont {(>>-) :: (a -> r) -> r}

instance Functor (Cont r) where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Cont r) a -> (Cont r) b
  fmap f (Cont cps_a) = Cont $ \cps -> cps_a (cps . f)

instance Applicative (Cont r) where
  -- pure :: a -> Cont r a
  pure x = Cont ($ x)
  -- (<*>) Cont r (a -> b) -> Cont r a -> Cont r b
  (Cont cps_f) <*> cont_cps_a = cps_f (\f -> fmap f cont_cps_a)
```

I am trying to use `fmap` in defining `(<*>)`, extracting `f` from the left cps value then `fmap f` over the right cps value. I am not sure where I made the mistake.

Comment: You're aware that `<*>` doesn't wrap its result in `Cont`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is obvious that the type of expression `cps_f (\f -> fmap f cont_cps_a)` is invalid . Since

```
fmap f cont_cps_a :: Cont r b
```

and

```
\f -> fmap f cont_cps_a :: (a->b)->Cont r b
```

and

```
cps_f :: ((a->b)->r)->r
```

`cps_f` need parameter type as `(a->b)->r`, but now is `(a->b)->Cont r b`.

Instead of using `fmap`, you still can implements `<*>` operator similar to the way as your `fmap` function as

```
(Cont cps_f) <*> Cont cps_a = Cont $ \cps_b -> cps_f (\f -> cps_a (cps_b . f))
```

Comment: Where does f come from? Cps_b is the next computation but f I don't see where it's coming from.